# How to create scroll triggered animations with fixed position in React

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, css-animations, tailwind-css

I want to achieve animation triggered by fixed position as below.(Here is the example)
I am using React, Typescript, Tailwind and tried to use `Framer Motion` and `React Spring` but couldn't find the perfect solution for this kind of animation.

[image: My Caption]

What I want to achieve is

- Animation is triggered by user scroll
- Fixed screen position, and animated elements come from down to start position
- All elements are shown in default (when the page loaded) as column style

Here is the example website that has the animation exactly what I want.

https://www.pelm.com/use-cases

I believe I can achieve this by using React Spring but not quite sure exact solution - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point is "position: sticky"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).